# How to print in color with Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebooks (using IPython) print in black and white by default.
  By opening the developer's console, locating the relevant style file, and deleting various `@media print` styling options, I can print in colors. 
However, this is rather tedious to do.

Is there a way to set up a global configuration to override the default?

```
Jupyter version: 4.0.6
IPython version: 4.0
```

Comment: I've filed an issue on the github site for Jupyter.

Comment: Andres issue: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/840,  Related issue: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a patch just got accepted on this topic: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/3212.

It's apparently something of a hack because the offending code/template is pretty deep within a dependency. While it is being fixed by the dependency upstream, the newer version of the dependency is incompatible, so a more hack-ish patch is acceptable for now.

The fix just got accepted into the master branch of the source code, so it isn't yet available in a released version. If someone sees that it is, then this answer should be updated or a new answer submitted.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround that I use:

1. File > Print Preview
2. In the preview tab, press Ctrl+A (Select All)
3. Print > Print selection only

Answer (score 0):

Like [flutefreak7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48400984/2056125) mentioned the issue is fixed.

If you are using an older version and you can't / don't want to upgrade, a workaround would be using the developer console / inspector of your browser to delete the color-set line in the media print section.

In Firefox you can solve this by:

1. Right click -> *Inspect Element (Q)*
2. Select the *Style Editor* tab
3. Press `Strg+F` and search for `@media print`
4. Delete or uncomment the line `color: #000 !important;` in the `*:after` section
5. Close the Inspector and enjoy printing in color mode!